i want to design a design a sidebar with concave rounded corners on the top and bottom edges for the right side using HTML, CSS, and Tailwind CSS?
I am designing a sidebar where the active item should have concave curves on the top-right and bottom-right corners. I'm using Tailwind CSS for styling, and I initially tried setting borderTopRightRadius: '0%' and borderBottomRightRadius: '0%', but it results in straight lines, not the concave curves I want. Here's a sample of what I want to achieve (include image here).
How can I style my sidebar so that when an item is active, the right side has concave curves, both upwards and downwards?
<li
  className={`flex rounded-3xl w-[115%] p-2 cursor-pointer text-gray-300 text-sm items-center gap-x-2 ${
    location.pathname === menu.path ? 'active-item' : ''
  } hover:bg-white hover:text-black transition duration-300`}
>
  <Link to={menu.path} className="flex items-center gap-x-4 w-full">
    <span className="icon">{menu.icon}</span>
    <span className={`${!open && 'hidden'} origin-left duration-200`}>
      {menu.title}
    </span>
  </Link>
</li>


What I Tried:

I set borderTopRightRadius and borderBottomRightRadius to 0%, but it results in straight edges.

I tried different border-radius values, but I can't get the concave shape I'm looking for.


Desired Design: I want the right side of the active menu item to have a concave curve similar to what you can see in this image (attach your reference image).
Solution Needed: How can I use Tailwind CSS or custom CSS to get concave curves on the top-right and bottom-right corners of the active sidebar item?


[sidebar which i have created.]

You're going to make use of :before and :after properties with custom css.

https://css-shape.com/inner-curve/

no. i am not using :before and :after prosperities i will try now and let you know.

It could be better if you shared html code, so we could try on. You have html tag, but code is in React.

This might be helpful: Codepen Link
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="innerbox select">
    Home
</div>
  <div class="innerbox select">
    Contact
</div>
  <div class="innerbox">
    Profile
</div>
</div>

.outerbox {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.innerbox {
  padding: 1.5rem 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


.select::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.select::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 0;
}

.innerbox:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}



This might not be full answer.  I am providing this to you this so that you can take from here.
<section>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="holder container">
      <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
h3 {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
}
section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12em, 1fr));
    gap: 1rem;
    place-content: center;
    width: 75%;
    margin-block: 2em;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background: #fb3e21;
    border-radius: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.holder {
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 6em;
    height: 4em;
    background: #fff;
}
.holder::before, 
.holder::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 3.65em;
  height: 1.25em;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {
    inset: calc(50% - 2em) 0 0 calc(100% - 10em);
    border-top-left-radius: 2.25em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2.25em;
}
.container::before {
    inset: -1.25em 0 0 calc(100% - .25em);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 0 0.3em #fff;
}
.container::after {
    inset: 100% 0 0 calc(100% - .25em);
  border-top-right-radius: 1.25em;
  box-shadow: 0.3em -0.3em 0 0.3em #fff;
}

.button:hover .one {
    background: green;
}
.button:hover .one::before {
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 0 0.3em #ffb200;
}
.button:hover .one::after {
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 0 0.3em #ffb200;
}

.button {
    width: 3em;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

